# Numerical algorithms made stable by unums which are unstable on IEEE floats

Tags: stability, floating-point, accuracy

For [unums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unum_(number_format)), there is [good evidence](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3190339.3190344) (see figure 5) that accuracy is better than IEEE floats. (Note: I use the term "unum" broadly to refer to any of the various iterations and revisions to the format.)

However, generally we regard "stability as more of a constraint than accuracy". Are there numerical algorithms which can be made stable using some unum format that is unstable using IEEE floating point?

Comment: In your experience, can unums be largely described as (variable length) multi-precision intervals, so that algorithms, correctly implemented, return the "best possible" approximation and a correct (possibly too pessimistic) error bound?

Comment: Does "good evidence" compare on comparable memory footprint and run-time, or only on accuracy?

Comment: @LutzLehmann: Only on accuracy. Runtime is not really a fair comparison since IEEE is run on hardware and unums have to be run in software. Memory footprint is again debatable, since the claim at least is that for a given bit budget they are better, but since they're variable length you can't get vectors must use linked lists.

Comment: Implicit in the question is "given that we're put so much effort into hardware implementations of IEEE floating point, would there be any real benefit to doing a hardware implementation of unums?"

Comment: Maybe start by asking the reverse question: What numerical algorithms currently suffer because they are using FP numbers that provide insufficient accuracy? (I can't think of much in this regard, but it's also not exactly my field.)

Comment: How about how Gaussian elimination is not guaranteed to be stable? (Most matrices are stable under Gaussian elimination in floating point, but there exist matrices which diverge.)

Comment: Intermediate matrices to generate matrices for Winograd minimal filtering: https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.00977

Comment: Calculation of Gauss-Kronrod nodes/weights: https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1997-66-219/S0025-5718-97-00861-2/S0025-5718-97-00861-2.pdf

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/college.math.j.42.5.396

Comment: Isolating real roots of a polynomial is highly dependent on the precision of your arithmetic, but I don't think other than a few token cases would unums perform significantly better than IEEE floats.

Comment: Strassen's matrix multiplication also has decreased stability relative to the naive O(n^3) method: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/800119.803910

Comment: Gaussian elimination is not a good example. We use pivoting to avoid the issue.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: "Yet it was realized in around 1960 by
Wilkinson and others that for certain exceptional matrices, Gaussian elimination is still unstable, even with
pivoting" https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/NAessay.pdf

Comment: Kahan's [talk](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/UnumSORN.pdf) on unums is terse, but highly relevant to anyone contemplating the use of unums.

Comment: @user14717 Well yes, of course it is. The question is whether any other system of representing numbers would be better suited in those cases. If a matrix is so poorly conditioned that 64-bit FP numbers are not sufficient, my claim is that *no* other system that doesn't use vastly more bits would be sufficient. That's the fundamental reason why 128-bit FP numbers are not widely used: The problems for which 64-bit numbers are not enough are so ill-conditioned that they can not be solved by representing numbers with a small number of additional bits.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: If you have a proof for that claim then put it as an answer!

Comment: None other than experience.

Comment: Re: "would there be any real benefit to doing a hardware implementation of unums?" The inventor of unums has kind of answered that by following up with posits, which are better suited for hardware implementation. Even so, it is a mixed bag: Florent de Dinechin, Luc Forget, Jean-Michel Muller, Yohann Uguen, "Posits: the good, the bad and the ugly", HAL Preprint hal-01959581v3, March 2019 (v3) ([online](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01959581v3)).